# The dihedral group $V\langle\alpha\rangle$

Tags: group-theory

Let  $S_4$, the symmetric group on four symbols.
Let $V$ denote the normal subgroup of order four in $S_4$ and choose an involution $\alpha\in S_4\setminus V$.
The Sylow 2-subgroup $D$ of $S_4$ is $V\langle\alpha\rangle$ is the dihedral group of order 8.
Choose an involtion $\beta\in V$.

Proof that $V=\langle\beta,\beta ^{\alpha }\rangle $ and $D=\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle$.

Help!

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but if by $\,V\langle\alpha\rangle\,$ you mean the product subgroup something's fishy here since the dihedral group of order 8 has *cyclic* subgroup of order $4$ and the group $\,V\lhd S_4\,$ is the Klein group...

Comment: user2040:Yes! Is Klein.

Comment: There is nothing fishy, and you should just do it! $V = \{1,  (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3) \}$. Let's choose $\alpha = (1,2)$. (Since all choices of $\alpha$ are conjugate, it doesn't matter which one we choose.) In fact what you write is not true for  $\beta = (1,2)(3,4)$, which is centralized by $\alpha$. But it is true for $\beta = (1,3)(2,4)$, so now you can just do the calculations.

Comment: I did the calculations and they gave right. Thank you!